# Firebase (GeoFire) saves data twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm trying to save `GeoLocations` with `GeoFire` in Firebase, the key of the `GeoLocation` must be the server timestamp. So the data model is as follows:

```
{
  "geofire" : {
    "1515755844766" : {
      ".priority" : "ez53wur36x",
      "g" : "ez53wur36x",
      "l" : [ 39.66227391798104, -6.372992321848869 ]
    },
    "1515755844962" : {
      ".priority" : "ez53wur36x",
      "g" : "ez53wur36x",
      "l" : [ 39.66227391798104, -6.372992321848869 ]
    },
    "1515755851938" : {
      ".priority" : "s6xhjeruen",
      "g" : "s6xhjeruen",
      "l" : [ 14.78428771229891, 21.346221640706066 ]
    },
    "1515755852148" : {
      ".priority" : "s6xhjeruen",
      "g" : "s6xhjeruen",
      "l" : [ 14.78428771229891, 21.346221640706066 ]
    }
  },
  "serverTime" : 1515755852148
}
```

I just executed the following code twice to get those values (four values), so it saves key (timestamp) twice for each `.setLocation()`, with a small diference in miliseconds and seconds.

Why could this be happening?

```
//Get reference to Firebase DB
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// Get reference to Geofire inside FIrebaseDB
dbRefGeofire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("geofire");
geoFire = new GeoFire(dbRefGeofire);

dbRef.child("serverTime").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);    //Executes TIMESTAMP function in firebase server and stores that value
dbRef.child("serverTime").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {    //Gets TIMESTAMP value from the server
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        serverTime = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                        geoFire.setLocation(serverTime, new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override       //Save geolocation with timestamp in seconds
                            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                                if (error != null) {
                                    Log.v("Informe","There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
                                } else {
                                    Log.v("Informe","Location saved on server successfully!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: What is geoFire ref?

Comment: @Nirel Sorry, I've edited the post and added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String serverTime = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));

        geoFire.setLocation(serverTime, new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.v("Informe","There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
                } else {
                    Log.v("Informe","Location saved on server successfully!");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
dbRef.child("serverTime").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this won't work, as the .setLocation() method needs as first argument a String, and ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a <Map>. In addition, if I try to parse it, it won't work because ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a function that must be run on serverside.

Comment: I understand. Tell me pelase, why do you need the key of the GeoLocation to be the server timestamp?

Comment: It's a requirement in the data model of my project, in order to do actions when location insertion time is the desired one.

Comment: Not it works Alex. Thank you so much :) How did you know about this? Just being curious.

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` listens for an event only once and this what you needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The ValueEventListener excuted twice, if you will set breakpoint at                         `serverTime = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());`
you will see it clearly,

**Why that's happen?**

because your `dbRef.child("serverTime").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);` is async,
The application continue to run and set a new valueEventListener,

which will call immediately without any data in dataSnapshot

and then, when you async 'setValue' function will finish and 'onDataChange' will call again (because that the value has been changed)

You can just add 'datasnapshout.isExist()' to solve it,

or add 'onCompleteListener' to your setValue line like this:

```
    dbRef.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference dataRef) {
dbRef.child("serverTime").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {    //Gets TIMESTAMP value from the server
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        serverTime = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                   geoFire.setLocation(serverTime, new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override       //Save geolocation with timestamp in seconds
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            Log.v("Informe","There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);


                 } else {
                                Log.v("Informe","Location saved on server successfully!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

});

Comment: Hey Nirel, I've tried your solution but it still sets 2 values. So I thought about that dataSnapshot.exists() solution, but Idk how it could help with this problem, as it inserts 2 differents values in the database (sorry, they are not duplicated, my bad), thank you :)